# Passing a lambda function as a parameter to a method that expects an Interface

Tags: java

I have a Java Interface `InterfaceA` that defines 3 methods with different signatures (2 of them are defaulted).

Another class defines a method like so:

```
public void f(InterfaceA ia) {
    .....
}
```

and in the unit test this is how this is used:

```
f((ArgA) -> return ArgA.write())
```

How is this possible knowing that `InterfaceA` defines 3 methods?

Comment: Read about lambda expressions.

Comment: I did. I still don't see what is happening here. I could guess that the lambda is overiding the interface method but how? which one? and why aren't we defining an anonymous class instead?

Comment: The lambda expression is supplying an implementation of the single method of your functional interface `InterfaceA`. It behaves very similarly to an anonymous class instance.

Comment: OK that would make sense if `InterfaceA` had only 1 method, but it has 3, the 2 others are defaulted.

Comment: `which one?` - there can be only one (at least one abstract method), or this wouldn't pass compilation.

Comment: @Kam the lambda expression gives an implementation to the single abstract method of the functional interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), the fact that an interface implements *n* methods doesn't mean it doesn't qualify as a valid interface. The details of these methods is what matters.

> Conceptually, **a functional interface has exactly one abstract method.
>   Since default methods have an implementation, they are not abstract.**
>   If an interface declares an abstract method overriding one of the
>   public methods of java.lang.Object, that also does not count toward
>   the interface's abstract method count since any implementation of the
>   interface will have an implementation from java.lang.Object or
>   elsewhere. (emphasis mine)

So, it depends on the interface in question. It sounds like your interface is defined appropriately.